# Evaluate the given limit

Tags: calculus, limits

Given a function $f : R → R$ for which $|f(x) − 3| ≤ x^2$. Find

$$\lim_{ x\to0}\frac{f(x) - \sqrt{x^2 + 9}}{x}$$

Can  the function $f(x)$  be considered as  $x^2 + 3$  and go about evaluating the limit using the Limit laws?

Comment: Apply the squeeze theorem.

Comment: Interesting, I hadn't considered that but I only have one side of the interval.

Comment: How about $|f(x) - \sqrt{x^2 + 9}| \leq x^2 + |3 - \sqrt{x^2 + 9}|$?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> **"Can  the function $f(x)$  be considered as  $x^2 + 3$  and go about solving the limit using the Limit laws?"**

No, since we have only that $|f(x)-3|\le x^2\implies 3-x^2\le f(x)\le 3+x^2$.

> But we can proceed by using $\color{blue}{f(x)-3=O(x^2)}$, where we are using the (["Big O notation"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Big_O_notation#Formal_definition)).

Then, we can evaluate the limit of interest by writing

$$\begin{align}
\frac{f(x)-\sqrt{x^2+9}}{x}&=\frac{f(x)-3\left(1+\frac{x^2}{9}\right)^{1/2}}{x}\\\\
&=\frac{f(x)-3\left(1+\color{red}{\frac12 \frac{x^2}{9}+O(x^4)}\right)}{x}\\\\
&=\frac{\color{blue}{\left(f(x)-3\right)}+\color{red}{O(x^2)}}{x}\\\\
&=\frac{\color{blue}{O(x^2)}+\color{red}{O(x^2)}}{x}\\\\
&=O(x)\to 0\,\,\text{as}\,\,x\to 0
\end{align}$$

And we are done!

Comment: This still doesn't solve the limit

Comment: Is there any reason as to why the first statement is defined?

Comment: Gary, not that $|x|\le y$ implies that $-y\le x\le y$.

Comment: @SimplyBeautifulArt It's a bit embarrassing.  I had edited the question and not digested it fully.  I've edited accordingly.  Thank you for alerting me!  -Mark

Comment: May I also ask as to how the simplification within the braces in step 2 was achieved ?

Comment: Also the 3 is taken out after dividing (x square + 9) by 9 how can f(x) -3 be grouped?

Comment: Gary note that $3\left(1+z\right)=3+3z$.  And to answer the previous comment, recall from the binomial theorem $(1+x)^a=1+ax+\frac{a(a-1)}{2}x^2+\cdots$=1+ax+O(x^2)$.

Answer (score 1):

We have $|f(x)-\sqrt{x^2 +9}| = |f(x)-3 + 3 - \sqrt{x^2 + 9}| \le |f(x)-3| + |3 - \sqrt{x^2+9}| \le x^2 + |3 - \sqrt{x^2 + 9}|$. So:

$$\left|\frac{f(x)-\sqrt{x^2+9}}{x}\right| \le |x| + \left| \frac{\sqrt{x^2+9}-3}{x}\right|$$

Now squeeze.

Comment: How did you get the above expression?

Comment: @GaryAndrews30 $|f(x)-\sqrt{x^2 +9}| = |f(x)-3 + 3 - \sqrt{x^2 + 9}| \le |f(x)-3| + |3 - \sqrt{x^2+9}|$

Comment: The given interval should be simplified to f(x) to squeeze, the left side of the interval would be 0. How can the expression be simplified?

Answer (score 0):

Apply law |a+b| <= |a| + |b|

Let $L = \frac{f(x)-\sqrt{x^2+9}}{x}$

$$
|L| = \lvert\frac{f(x) - 3 + 3 - \sqrt{x^2+9}}{x}\rvert \le |\frac{f(x)-3}{x}| + |\frac{3 - \sqrt{x^2+9}}{x}| \\
\le |\frac{x^2}{x}| + |\frac{(3-\sqrt{x^2+9})(3+\sqrt{x^2+9})}{x(3+\sqrt{x^2+9})}| = |x| + |\frac{x}{3+\sqrt{x^2+9}}|
$$

Hence,
$$
\lim_{x \rightarrow 0}{|L|} \le \lim_{x \rightarrow 0}{(|x| + |\frac{x}{3+\sqrt{x^2+9}}|)} = 0 \quad (1)
$$

Since $|L| \ge 0 \quad \forall x$,  we also have $\lim_{x \rightarrow 0}{|L|} \ge 0 \quad (2)$

From (1) and (2) we have $\lim_{x \rightarrow 0}{|L|} = 0$, or  $\quad \lim_{x \rightarrow 0}L = 0$